# How To Make User Input Multiple Lines

Tags: c++, loops, input, cin, getline

I would like to make the user be able to input multiple lines of strings. I've been trying with a for loop, but so far only the last line is returned.

For example, the user inputs the following string and lines.
`string str;`
`getline(cin, str);`

or a loop
`for(i=0;i<n;i++){`
`getline(cin, str);}`

*These are the input the user enters*

> Basketball Baseball Football //line 1
>
> Hockey Soccer Boxing" //line 2

Now, I wan to be able to return those two lines at one point. I don't know how to do that. 
Also, what I find more difficult is trying to figure out if the user only ones to enter one line, two or three. I understand how to dot hat with `cases`, but I want to now if there is an easier way that doesn't look that messy,

Comment: Try `while (std::getline(std::cin, std)) {...}`

Comment: I already tried that. It does takes multiple lines, but it never stops. If I try to do it manually, `ctrl+Z` then the nothing happens. It doesn't run the rest of the program.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know what you think. If you like it, please upvote and accept (green tick below the votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `std::getline` in a while loop, so that once the empty line is entered, loop exits, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    while (getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty()) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    std::cout << "User has entered " << lines.size() << " lines" << std::endl;
    for (auto const& l : lines) {
        std::cout << l << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "... End of program ..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can store each line user has entered into the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container and retrieve those lines again later.

Possible output:

```
First line
Second line

User has entered 2 lines
First line
Second line
... End of program ...
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to enable user to enter only 2 lines and if you want to use for loop, then you can do something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    std::cout << "User has entered " << lines.size() << " lines" << std::endl;
    for (auto const& l : lines) {
        std::cout << l << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "... End of program ..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output could be:

```
First line                                                                                                                                                                         
Second line                                                                                                                                                                        
User has entered 2 lines                                                                                                                                                           
First line                                                                                                                                                                         
Second line                                                                                                                                                                        
... End of program ...
```

Comment: I'm nor sure what you did with the "vector". I don't use 'std::'. Is there another way without using vector?

Comment: So, I got one step closer.                                                                                          
`for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ getline(cin, str); }`  I use this, but the problem with that is that it only returns the last line. I want both lines to be return.

Comment: @Joe take a look at the updated answer. The reason why it returns you only the last line is because you are overwriting your `str` with each iteration of a for loop. That's why you need to use something like `std::vector`